# Nested Query Alternatives in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I am running a query that gives a non-overlapping set of first_party_id's - ids that are associated with one third party but not another. This query does not run in Athena, however, giving the error: `Correlated queries not yet supported.`

Was looking at prestodb docs,   https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html (Athena is prestodb under the hood), for an alternative to nested queries. The  `with statement` example given doesn't seem to translate well for this `not in` clause. Wondering what the alternative to a nested query would be - Query below.

```
SELECT 
         COUNT(DISTINCT i.third_party_id) AS uniques
FROM 
         db.ids i
WHERE
         i.third_party_type = 'cookie_1'
         AND i.first_party_id NOT IN (
           SELECT
             i.first_party_id
           WHERE 
             i.third_party_id = 'cookie_2'
         )
```

Answer (score 18):

There may be a better way to do this - I would be curious to see it too!  One way I can think of would be to use an outer join.  (I'm not exactly sure about how your data is structured, so forgive the contrived example, but I hope it would translate ok.)  How about this?

```
with 
  a as (select * 
       from (values 
       (1,'cookie_n',10,'cookie_2'), 
       (2,'cookie_n',11,'cookie_1'),
       (3,'cookie_m',12,'cookie_1'),
       (4,'cookie_m',12,'cookie_1'),
       (5,'cookie_q',13,'cookie_1'),
       (6,'cookie_n',13,'cookie_1'),
       (7,'cookie_m',14,'cookie_3')
       ) as db_ids(first_party_id, first_party_type, third_party_id, third_party_type)
      ),
  b as (select first_party_type 
        from a where third_party_type = 'cookie_2'),
  c as (select a.third_party_id, b.first_party_type as exclude_first_party_type 
        from a left join b on a.first_party_type = b.first_party_type 
        where a.third_party_type = 'cookie_1')
select count(distinct third_party_id) from c 
       where exclude_first_party_type is null;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, figured out with statements are the way to go! You can also nest with statements -> `with x as ( with y as (...), z as (...) ....)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an outer join:

```sql
SELECT 
         COUNT(DISTINCT i.third_party_id) AS uniques
FROM 
         db.ids a
LEFT JOIN
         db.ids b
ON       a.first_party_id = b.first_party_id
     AND b.third_party_id = 'cookie_2'
WHERE
         a.third_party_type = 'cookie_1'
     AND b.third_party_id is null -- this line means we select only rows where there is no match
```

You should also use caution when using `NOT IN` for subqueries that may return `NULL` values since the condition will always be true. Your query is comparing `a.first_party_id` to `NULL`, which will always be false and so `NOT IN` will lead to the condition always being true. Nasty little gotcha.

One way to avoid this is to avoid using `NOT IN` or to add a condition to your subquery i.e. `AND third_party_id IS NOT NULL`.

See [here](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/consider-using-not-exists-instead-not-subquery) for a longer explanation.